# JQuery not working after null ajax responce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#login').click(      
        function () {
            $.post('/profile/ajax/login', {
                    username: $('#username').val(),
                    password: $('#password').val(),
                },
                function (res) {
                    if (res != null) {
                        $.each(res, function (i, val) {
                            $('#login-error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger fade in"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>' + val + '!</div>');
                            return false;
                        });
                    } else { 
                        location.reload();
                    }
                },
                'json'
            );
        }
    );
}
```

And have PHP code

```
if($_POST)
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $post = Validation::factory($_POST);
        $post->rule('username', 'not_empty');
        $post->rule('password', 'not_empty');

        if($post->check())
        {
            if(!Auth::instance()->login($username, $password, true))
            {
                echo json_encode(array('Неверный Логин или Пароль'));   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $errors = $post->errors('validation');
            echo json_encode($errors);
        }           
    }
```

If Ajax return some text with errors (res != null) - Jquery work normally. 
If Ajax returned without any information nothing happens in "else" block.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: remove the `return false;`

Answer (score 1):

The datatype you specified is json and so if the return value is null then it wont be processed. Try changing the datatype or echo an error in json format in your php file :)

Comment: but he gets null... he says if some error is returned then the code works, the else part doesn't work if null is returned.

Comment: @empiric not all branches lead to an execution of `json_encode`

Answer (score 0):

The check `res != null` is the problem. An empty array can't be compared to `null`. 
Change the condition to check the array length:

```
if (res.length > 0) {
```

Secondly if the submitted credentials are in valid format and are correct, the PHP returns nothing. This will cause the jQuery `error` handler to fire instead of `success` because a blank response can't be parsed as JSON. Add another else clause that returns an empty array:

```
if(!Auth::instance()->login($username, $password, true)){
    echo json_encode(array('Неверный Логин или Пароль'));   
} else {
    echo json_encode(array());   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your PHP code to :

```
$result = null;
if($_POST)
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $post = Validation::factory($_POST);
    $post->rule('username', 'not_empty');
    $post->rule('password', 'not_empty');

    if($post->check())
    {
        if(!Auth::instance()->login($username, $password, true))
        {
            $result = array('Неверный Логин или Пароль');   
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $result = $post->errors('validation');
    }           
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

This would result in your result being json encoded in all possible cases.